# get data between two dates but I have two separate columns for date and time respectively

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, filtering

I have two columns in my database one for date(receive date) in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format and one column for time(receive time) in 'hours:minutes:seconds' format

[image: table data]

I want to query for data where `receive_date` starts from '2022-02-10' and `receive_time`greter than '15:00:00' till `receive_date` is '2022-02-17' and `receive_time` is less than '17:00:00'.

Keep in mind that `receive_time` for date '2022-02-10' is greater than '15:00:00' but for the next date '2022-02-18' the `receive_time` not matters till the end date, Similarly for the `end_date` '2022-02-17' I want data till `receive_time` is '17:00:00'.

Comment: How about `CONCAT()`? `WHERE '2022-02-10 15:00:00' < CONCAT(DateSent, TimeSent) AND '2022-02-17 17:00:00' > CONCAT(Recive_Date, Receive_Time)`

Comment: @GigiSan can you give more detailed query... I am not familiar with ```CONCAT()```

Comment: hey @GigiSan this worked ```select * from aeron.Device_200011555585431 where CONCAT(Receive_Date,' ',Receive_Time) between '2022-02-10 15:00:00' and '2022-02-17 17:00:00';``` Thank You!!!

Comment: You're right, I forgot the space. Let me post an official answer. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 5):

You could join the two strings with a `CONCAT()` and then check if the result is between your date/time range. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM aeron.Device_200011555585431
WHERE CONCAT(Receive_Date, ' ', Receive_Time)
    BETWEEN '2022-02-10 15:00:00' AND '2022-02-17 17:00:00';
```

Keep in mind that `CONCAT()` might be a bit expensive as a comparison term if the table you're querying has millions of records.

### UPDATE

An alternative to using `CONCAT()` might checking every combination of `Receive_Date` and `Receive_Time` you need to cover the required time span.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM aeron.Device_200011555585431
WHERE ( Receive_Date = '2022-02-10' AND Receive_Time > '15:00:00' )
   OR ( Receive_Date > '2022-02-10' AND Receive_Date < '2022-02-17' )
   OR ( Receive_Date = '2022-02-17' AND Receive_Time < '17:00:00' );
```

Should be less expensive than `CONCAT()` if `Receive_Date` and `Receive_Time` are indexed, not sure in the opposite case.

**Another** alternative would be refactoring the table by fusing the two columns in a proper `DATETIME` type.

Comment: If using ```CONCAT()``` is expensive then is there any alternative?

Comment: @shubham see UPDATE